# Working on projects on GitLab from untrusted computers

Tags: git, security, gitlab

I'm new to Git and GitLab (Hosted GitLab.com). I created a private repository. I want to work on it from a computer that i can't trust, so i don't want to log in with my account. I know that i can use access token but it will give full access to repository, including pushing. Is there a way (without creating another account) to allow this computer to access it but don't allow pushing without request, so that i can request from untrusted oc and then when i'm back home approve this request? Or any other ways to do something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You could clone the repository with http instead of ssh. For me, http has always asked me to type in my login/password when using http.

Comment: On an untrusted computer there could be a keylogger that catches your http credentials. The OP asks how to configure Gitlab so that there is a separate read-only login; that read-only login will be used on untrusted computers.